# java: how to handle null in several function parameters at once?

Tags: java

I have a function which takes in three strings, and any of them or all three might be null (not known in advance).  What is the best way to handle this?

The base case is this:

```
public String doStuff(String a, String b, String c) {
  //do stuff
}
```

If this is called with nulls in any of the strings, I get this error:

```
-> doStuff("test", null, null)

Unable to execute method public java.lang.String
doStuff(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)  
on object 1c52ac68 of class test with arguments {Wap:java.lang.String, null, null} of size 3
```

I guess I could overload this for all the possible permutations of nulls in the three inputs, but is there a better way?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, or where the validation is currently occurring.

Comment: the function fails before anything is executed because the NULL type doesn't match java.lang.String.  So I never even make it inside the function

Comment: If the string is null are you still calling the method with all 3 parameters?

Comment: @vasek1: Show us how you call the method, please.

Comment: if(a==null){a=new String();} and do it for b and c int he doStuff

Comment: edited to show the function call

Comment: The function call does not show the object.

Comment: @vasek1: That should not fail. See [this example](http://ideone.com/Liif0). Can you please show us the exact code that gives the error?

Comment: @vasek1: That should be fine. Please show a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: "the function fails before anything is executed because the NULL type doesn't match java.lang.String. So I never even make it inside the function" = nonsense

Comment: what is Wap in "Wap:java.lang.String" ?

Answer (score 1):

You can write like that:

```
int nulls=0;
if(a==null) nulls+=1;
if(b==null) nulls+=2;
if(c==null) nulls+=4;
```

and then switch nulls:

```
switch(nulls){
  case 0://no String is null  
    ...  
    break;  
  case 1://just a is null  
    ...  
    break;
  case 5://(5=101b), a and c is null
    ...
    ...
}
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to get around your issue, but if you're just trying to make it easier to check, you could make a utility function to check if any of the parameters is null:

```
public boolean verifyNotNull(Object.. objects) {
    for(Object o : objects) {
        if(o==null) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then you could call this utility in your function:

```
public String doStuff(String a, String b, String c) {
    if(!verifyNotNull(a,b,c)) {
        throw new MyException("...");
    }
}
```

Maybe AOP could do something for you too..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whats the end result you want. If you say your doStuff just do a string concat and you don't need a null in that then do this..

```
doStuff(String a, String b, String c){
        String x = "";
        if(null!=a) x = x+a;
        if(null!=b) x =x+b;
        if(null!=c) x = x+c;
        System.out.println(x);
}
```